# Laravel dynamic page title in navbar-brand

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, dynamic

I have layouts.app.blade.php where I have my `<html>` and `<body>` tags and also the `<nav>`.
In the `<body>` I yield content for every page, so they basically extend this app.blade.php.
All basic Laravel stuff so now I have this:

```
 <div class="navbar-header">
    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#spark-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- Branding Image -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        *Dynamic page title*
    </a>
</div>
// ...
@yield('content')
```

And I would like to use this `<a class="navbar-brand">` to display my pagetitle. So this means it has to change for each template that is loaded (with @yield('content')) in this 'parent.blade.php'.

How would I do this using Laravel 5.2?

Many thanks

Comment: Augmenting the above solution on using the variable in your view, if you are extending a layout(you should), then you can render it like so if you have a title section:
@section("title","$letter"). Thanks to the power of Blade. Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If this is your master page title below

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
    @section('sidebar')
        This is the master sidebar.
    @show

    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
```

then your page title can be changed in your blade page like below

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')
@parent

<p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
<p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

More information can be found here [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#template-inheritance)

Comment: Oh well, that's pretty straight forward. Works like a charm.

Comment: I was always trying to name the titles from controllers but now I see that yours is better. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7):

You can pass it to a view for example

**Controller**

```
$title = 'Welcome';

return view('welcome', compact('title'));
```

**View**

```
isset($title) ? $title : 'title';
```

or php7

```
$title ?? 'title';
```

> [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative that has worked for me in Laravel 9 and PHP 8 is to use a prop in a master layout. In my project I have only one layout so it's simple:

```
<x-layout :title="' - Page Title'">
  <!-- content -->
</x-layout>
```

Then in the `layout.blade.php` file:

```
@props(['title'])
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Static Title{{$title ?? ""}}</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    {{$slot}}
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Extremely simple and helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Define this title in this format as given below in the main file like as (master.blade.php)

```
<title>Vendor | @yield('mytitle') </title>
```

on page
here All Company is my new title for the blade file you want to dynamic title on this page

```
@section('mytitle', 'All Company')
```

Answer (score 1):

in your controller declare a variable called title & compact it as below

```
    public function aboutUs()
    {
        //page title
        $title = 'Project | About Us';
        return view('project.about_us', compact('title'));
    }
```

in your view page call the variable as below

```
<title>{{ $title }}</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can try to put `@stack('title')`
instead of the `title` tag in you header.blade.php file
and then put this in your `page.blade.php` file:

```
@push('title')
    <title> Home Page</title>
@endpush
@section('main-container')
Your content
@endsection
```