# Navbar title not showing in laravel

Tags: laravel, navbar

for some reason when I try to add in a title for my page, inside my navbar, it not showing up. I am currently trying to create a title for every page I have inside the navbar and I have researched a lot and one of the resources that was helpful was this,[Laravel dynamic page title in navbar-brand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497428/laravel-dynamic-page-title-in-navbar-brand), I tried following it but for some reason, my title isn't showing. Could it be because I have put my @yield and @section wrongly? So sorry because it my first time using this function since most of the time I would just follow tutorial video in doing it.

app.blade.php (sorry I don't really know where to put it)

```
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                        <title>@yield('title')</title>

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}" style="color: white">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="background-color:blue" style="color:white">
                                    <b>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</b> <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: blue">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();" style="background-color: blue" style="color: white">
                                            <b>Logout</b>
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

home.blade.php(this is where I want the title to be shown)

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Summary')
@section('content')
<link href="{{ asset('css/homeStyle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<table class="table table-bordered"> 
 <tr> 
 <th><strong><big>Name: </big></strong></th> 
 <th><strong><big>Action: </big></strong></th>
 </tr> 
 <td> 
 <tr> 
 @foreach($data as $value) 
 <tr> 
@if($value->blacklist == 'Yes')
 <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}"><span style="color: red;">{{$value->Name}}</a></th>
 @else 
<th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}">{{$value->Name}}</a></th>
 @endif  
 <th><form action="{{ url('/home/'.$value->pi_id.'/delete') }}" method="get"> 
 {{ csrf_field() }} 
 <button type="submit">Delete</button> 
 </form></th> 
 </tr> 
 @endforeach
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app.blade make sure you add in head tags

```
<head>
   <title>@yield('title')</title> 
</head>
```

Next, in your navbar header div

```
@yield('title')
```

Remove the title tags, not needed, as its stated in head tags

Your individual pages will then work as you have it now

```
@section('title', 'Summary')
```

before your content section
Hope that helps

Comment: Oh wow it work, thanks a lot @Jimmy, I just now also actually try putting in the head tag at my app.blade but doesn't work probably because of the title tags. Thank you so much for your help, I guess I can't use 2 title tag inside a blade