# Pass image in yield section in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For the `<title>` I've followed this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497428/laravel-dynamic-page-title-in-navbar-brand) This is working perfectly for  part but the image is not working

[Laravel dynamic page title in navbar-brand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497428/laravel-dynamic-page-title-in-navbar-brand)

But, Here when I try to make an image dynamic instead of title it's giving me a text instead of an image.

For instance,

**header.blade.php**

```
@yield('image')
```

In another blade, I called image as in section

```
@section('image', '<img src="http://localhost/appname/public/front/images/heading.png">')
```

Every page has a dynamic logo so I want to put logo dynamic the same like we're doing in the title.

But the result I'm getting is 
[image]

```
<img src="http://localhost/appname/public/front/images/heading.png">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
@section('image')
 <img src="http://localhost/appname/public/front/images/heading.png">
@endsection
```

Comment: Oh gosh, I was trying a difficult one. Thanks a lot, I appreciate.